# Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova Android App Iframe

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, iframe

I want to load a video in the Iframe using Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova.

I have tried loading a website like google and w3school but still failed to load the video.

I am using `document.getElementById("MyId").src = "site";`.

Sorry, I could not figure out how to add my full code in this question

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am using document.getElementById("MyId").src = "site"; Sorry I could figure out how to add my full code in this question

Comment: Why not load the video in the cordova html file itself?

Comment: Sounds like a goid idea. Could you provide an example or reference? I just started app design a couple of weeks ago. It is definitely not as easy as asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to play the video link in your cordova html files . 
Like this :

```
 <video id="example_video_1"  width="640" height="264"  webkit-playsinline poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" data-setup="{}">

            <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />

          </video>
```

but if you want to deploy for ios devices consider changing webconfig file and add this :

```
AllowInlineMediaPlayback=true
```

[refrence](https://gist.github.com/joshbuchea/4885b41e629ca8e432af)

Comment: The code did give me a video player but it still would not play the video. I since I have a Mac at home I switched over to xcode. I was able to build an Iphone app that will allow you to add your tube video streams into the apps. I love Visual Studio for work and handling datasets however I can not bridge this gap of the iframe or video for my video needs.

Comment: @bwaller Ok I edited my answer , before using youtube or other tubes try the sample using direct link video .

Comment: Thanks Ali, Your answer gives me an option if I cannot get the youtube stream to work in android. It looks like I will have to store the video on a different service. I was able to get it to work for ios via cocoapods library.

Comment: Hello Ali, I figured out what was the problem. I was trying to run all these feature off of the

Comment: Hello Ali, I figured out the problem. I was trying to run all these feature directly off the Android base system. Come to find out the new versions of Cordova don't let you run a lot of these features such as iframe directly through the index.html page. I had to create a test.html page and load it up in the inAppBrowser which allows the app to work like a regular html internet page. The iframe works the, mailto button pulls up external email apps and all! I'm new at this so let me know if that is not the way to do.